# Single HTML file showing in Firefox smaller than the other HTML files

Tags: html, css

I have a web site that I'm building using HTML and CSS. I have 3 pages built exactly the same minus the actual content on the page. The issue I'm having is that on Firefox, one of the pages shrinks. Everything from the Header down to the Footer and including icons shrink. When launched on Safari, it works fine. Any suggestions as to what to look into for the issue or why it would happen on Firefox? I've exchanged the CSS for the other pages and it hasn't changed. I know it's bad practice to have 3 HTML files that will look the same but to give them each their own CSS and I'll fix that now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Learn [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
2. check your **DOM** it may be causing the issue `doctype` or something bad structure, 
3. learn to use your `console` or `Inspect Element` or Firebug`

Comment: Simply stating Firebug would have been a great help. I've already noted in the question that everything is fine in the code. I'm going to throw this one up to you not trying to be rude but instead just your culture has conformed you to a certain way of using the English language. I'm not that well versed in web dev as others might be and do thoroughly google my issues before coming here. At any rate, good talk.

Comment: Accept my apologies if I was rude, but without any [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) no **SOuser** can help you into this.